# Unable To Loop a Protected Object From smsgateway.me

Tags: php

I am actually using smsgateway.me to receive and send sms the problem is that the response from api is being returned as an object and the properties in it are all protected i actually wanted it to show all the messages i received in a table format using foreach loop here is an example response.

```
SMSGatewayMe\Client\Model\MessageSearchResult Object
 (
[count:protected] => 59
[results:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => SMSGatewayMe\Client\Model\Message Object
            (
                [id:protected] => 63384039
                [deviceId:protected] => 89747
                [message:protected] => test m 2
                [status:protected] => sent
                [log:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SMSGatewayMe\Client\Model\MessageLog Object
                            (
                                [status:protected] => failed
                                [occurredAt:protected] => DateTime Object
                                    (
                                        [date] => 2018-05-13 21:14:49.000000
                                        [timezone_type] => 1
                                        [timezone] => +00:00
                                    )
                            )
                    )
                [createdAt:protected] => DateTime Object
                    (
                        [date] => 2018-05-13 21:14:49.000000
                        [timezone_type] => 1
                        [timezone] => +00:00
                    )
                [updatedAt:protected] =>
            )
    )
)
```

Here is my code

```
    $config = Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration();
$config->setApiKey('Authorization', 'my-api-key');
$apiClient = new ApiClient($config);
$messageClient = new MessageApi($apiClient);


$messages = $messageClient->searchMessages(
    [
        'filters' => [
            [
                [
                    'field' => '103150',
                    'operator' => '=',
                    'value' => '1'
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'status',
                    'operator' => '=',
                    'value' => 'received'
                ]
            ],

        ],
        'order_by' => [
            [


                'field'=> 'created_at',
                'direction'=> 'desc'


                // 'field' => 'status',
                // 'direction' => 'ASC'
            ],
        ],

    ]
);
       print_r($messages);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see objects with protected/private data, this is either information that is not 'usable' by a consumer, or something which should be available via the class methods.

As far as I can tell from reading the [source code of the API](https://github.com/smsgatewayme/client-php/tree/master/lib/Model)...

```
$msgs = $messages->getResults();
```

will give you the value of `[results:protected]`, which is a list of `Message` objects.

You can then...

```
   foreach ( $msgs as $msg ) {
       echo $msg->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
   }
```

This is purely from reading the source code via Github and so may not be how it is intended to work.

Or to build a list...

```
$msgOut = [];
foreach ( $msgs as $msg ) {
    $msgOut[] = ["msg" => $msg->getMessage()];  // Add other infor here
}
```

Comment: well this works but the problem is that it just displays all the messages not in an array but in a string format Will Doing an explode do the trick?

Comment: Where I am displaying `getMessage()` in the loop, you can look at the [source](https://github.com/smsgatewayme/client-php/blob/master/lib/Model/Message.php) to work out the information you need.

Comment: Ok Thanks i will look into this

Comment: Not everything is going to be presented exactly how you may want it, sometimes you have to take what is available and use it to create the result your after.

Comment: Thanks Buddy This Works Great